# Control custom properties

Tags: python, properties

How can I add remove and create a callback/event for a custom property using bpy. I have a scene, called `scene`, and I want to add a custom property named `x`, defulat value `2` (as intereger), and a callback `foo`, to run when it is changed. I also need to be able to read the value from it, and delete it. **How do I do this?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use static custom properties for this;

```
import bpy

def foo(self, context):
    print("my test function", self)

bpy.types.Scene.testprop = bpy.props.FloatProperty(update=foo)
```

This will print:

```
my test function <bpy_struct, Scene("Scene")
```

When the property is updated, through:

```
 bpy.context.scene.testprop = 11.0
```

Note that the FloatProperty function takes the arguments:

```
FloatProperty(name="", description="", default="", maxlen=0, options={'ANIMATABLE'}, subtype='NONE', update=None, get=None, set=None)
```

Which are all optional; This does, however mean, that you can define set and get functions for the property.

You can also use `StringProperty` and `BoolProperty`

If you want to add it to the UI, in a custom location, use something like:

```
class myPanel(bpy.types.Panel):     # panel to display new property
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"       # show up in: 3d-window
    bl_region_type = "UI"           # show up in: properties panel
    bl_label = "My Panel"           # name of the new panel

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(bpy.types.Scene, "testprop") #Make sure this matches the name you gave to your property.

bpy.utils.register_class(myPanel)
```

It will be found under the `Scene` tab, in the `Properties` panel, otherwise.

The custom property is basically a *field* and can be read, programatically, as:

```
bpy.type.Scene.testprop
```

And delete them with:

```
bpy.ops.wm.properties_remove(data_path="scene", property="testprop")
```

---

You can check the relevant docs [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties#Custom_properties), and the API [here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.props.html).

Comment: Yes, but how do  I read it.... though, and where in the UI is it going to show up?