# Create a radio button via python

Tags: python, interface

I want to create a own UI for a add-on which I am writing.
The user should have the ability to do different things with this add-on.
For example he can choose a cube or a pyramid. If cube or pyramid is choosen the ui will change. Some fields should be hidden and some should be visible.

Okay, first step: Create radio buttons. And now I am stuck :/

As far as I know I need a EnumProperty, which has the attribute items. Items has all the "values" the radio button can have.

Sadly it's not working for me.

I did this:

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj_types_enum = ('0','a','a')
        obj_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = obj_types_enum)

        layout.label("Select original form")

        col = layout.column()

        col.prop(self, 'obj_type')
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
# This is how you make a static enum prop for the scene
enum_items = (('0','Cube',''),('1','Pyramid',''))
bpy.types.Scene.obj_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = enum_items)

# This is how you display it in panel
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.label(text="Select Original Form")

    layout.prop(context.scene, 'obj_type', expand=True)
```

Comment: Uhu… didn’t even saw that :(

Comment: Thanks! Could you also say me how I can react to these buttons? For example when Cube is pressed execute a method. I could do this with a own button(bpy.types.Operator) and the execute(self, context) method. But I don't have them.

Comment: @Michael You can specify an update function for your property, it will be run everytime the property changes. The answer how is here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23399/control-custom-properties

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `col.prop(self, 'obj_type')` by `col.prop(self, 'obj_type', expand=True)`. This won’t give you real radio buttons, but each enum option will have its own toggle button, instead of having a single drop-down list.

Note you can have all your options in a row or in a column, depending on the direction of the current layout (`row()` and `split()` layouts are horizontal, `column()` and `box()` are vertical…).

There is no way to get real radio buttons currently in Blender py UI API, afaik (and you won’t find any in current interface).

Comment: Well you can make radio buttons with bool properties and with 'RADIOBUT_OFF' and 'RADIOBUT_ON' icons and handle their switching with code ;)

Comment: @Jerryno That’s what I call bad hacking! :P