# Python: How to code "changeover buttons"?

Tags: python, source-code

I would like to code three changeover buttons in python, that behave each other.

If you click on one, the others keep switched off. So you can change between their states. An example is found in Blenders Render Output area. See my screenshot.

The exmaple code is not really helpful, if I click on "Edit Source" and shows the function block only, without further code.

Can someone show me the python code for this behavior?

Thank you a lot!

[image]

Comment: I don't know python, but those are called "radio buttons" in programming 'speak'. Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30421/create-a-radio-button-via-python